# Azure App Service: Differences on registry key values between instances

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a legacy application that is deployed using Azure App Services, on a Windows OS. None of these instances was recently created (the newest was created somewhere around 2017).

There are multiple instances of these App Services that run the same WebApp for different clients, and I recently noticed differences in the instances registry keys.

On some of them, I have the .NET Framework key *SystemDefaultTlsVersions*, with its value set to 1. On the rest the key is not present.

Since the absence of this key is having side effects on some operations, I would like to ensure that all the instances have this key properly configured, but I haven't found documentation on how these keys can be added to the machine.

Is there a way to ensure that the key is injected in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

- Registry key is present on all instances of your Azure App Services, you can use a startup task or a startup script to add the key to the registry during the application deployment process.
- Create a startup script adds the registry key and its value, you can use a simple text editor to create a file with a .bat extension, such as `add_registry_key.bat`.

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319" /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Here I Configure `Web.config` file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="add_registry_key" path="add_registry_key.bat" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="bitness32" />
  </handlers>
  <cgi>
    <environmentVariables>
      <add name="CMD" value="/c" />
    </environmentVariables>
  </cgi>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <hiddenSegments>
        <add segment="add_registry_key.bat" />
      </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

- Trigger a deployment to the Azure App Service, either manually or by pushing your code changes to the deployment source repository.

[image]

- Deploy the application to Azure App Services, and the startup script should run during the application startup process and add the registry key to the instances.